# How to add "PromotedActions" for all SiteCollections or WebApplication wide

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to extend the PromotedActions with a new link for the company. I now how to create a PromotedAction but how can i provide/activate this for all SiteCollections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're relying on the feature framework and your site collections are from the same template you should consider feature stapling http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/05/feature-stapling.html
Note that won't enable it on the already created site collection.
Otherwise a powershelle script to enable your feature on targeted site collections should do the trick.